# How to check that string further doesn't contain a dot

Tags: javascript, regex

Maybe someone could help me with this:

I have a string such as `"1.something"`, `"1.0.something"` or `1.0.0.something`

The question is how can I check that there is no more dot in *something* section?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you gives us an example about a good string and a bad string please ?

Comment: Guys I don't understand why so harsh reaction with downvoting in the very first minute. If I had regex example I wouldn't ask you to help.

The meaning I don't know the second part of the string which I marked as "something". But the first part can has multiple dotes.

Comment: I like to use this website when trying to come up with a regex, it will test what you are trying and has a reference to help you find the correct regex:
https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks for tips. I'm using https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const re = /^(\d\.){1,3}([^.]+)$/;

console.log(re.test('1.0.0.somethdfs!!$%^$%ing')); // true
console.log(re.test('1.0.something')); // true
console.log(re.test('1.something')); // true

console.log(re.test('1.0.0.somet.hing')); // false
console.log(re.test('1.0.sometmjhi!!ng')); // true
console.log(re.test('1.somethim.ng')); // false
```

```
^ // the start of the string
(\d\.) // a digit followed by a period
{1,3} // between one and three times only
([^.]+) // everything after that doesn't include a period
$ // the end of the string
```

[Further demo](https://regex101.com/r/moU8tS/1)

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly =)

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you're looking for. Let me know if I can help any further.

`^(?:\d\.)+[^.]*$`

The key component is `[^.]*` which means 0 or more characters that are *not* `.`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pWVNQL/1)